# Add Javascript Code shorted URL Syntax

Tags: php, javascript

I want to short the URL from Social Share Buttons which are written in Javascript.
The Script http://plugins.in1.com/share/demo

A Part Code of Social Share Script

```
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
        this.share.settings = $.extend({}, this.share.defaults, options);
        var settings = this.share.settings,
        networks = this.share.settings.networks,
        theme = this.share.settings.theme,
        orientation = this.share.settings.orientation,
        affix = this.share.settings.affix,
        margin = this.share.settings.margin,
        pageTitle = this.share.settings.title||$(document).attr('title'),
        pageUrl = this.share.settings.urlToShare||$(location).attr('href'),
        pageDesc = "";

        $.each($(document).find('meta[name="description"]'),function(idx,item){
            pageDesc = $(item).attr("content");
        });

        // each instance of this plugin
        return this.each(function() {
            var $element = $(this),
            id=$element.attr("id"),
            u=encodeURIComponent(pageUrl),
            t=encodeURIComponent(pageTitle),
            d=pageDesc.substring(0,250),
            href;

            // append HTML for each network button
            for (var item in networks) {
                item = networks[item];
                href = helpers.networkDefs[item].url;
                href = href.replace('|u|',u).replace('|t|',t).replace('|d|',d)
                           .replace('|140|',t.substring(0,130));
                $("<a href='"+href+"' title='Share this page on "+item+
                    "' class='pop share-"+theme+" share-"+theme+"-"+item+"'></a>")
                            .appendTo($element);
            }

            // bind click
            $('.pop').click(function(){
                window.open($(this).attr('href'),'t','toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=0,width=640,height=528');
                return false;
            });


        });// end plugin instance

    }
```

My Script is doing in PHP which shorts visited Pages URL.
The PHP Code for shortning URL

```
$short = file_get_contents('http://doma.in/api.php?api=sUio8Sy&url=' . urlencode('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Calling the PHP Code

```
$url=json_decode($short,TRUE);
echo $url['short'];
```

This is to do here but I am not sure how

```
u=encodeURIComponent(pageUrl),
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Also you have used `this` keyword improperly. It will cause problem later.

Comment: The Script is not mine. Well I dont know much about Javascript. Thats why having the trouble. Want to short the Page URL and let the shorted URL share on Social Sites.